# What does this notation mean? (See the picture.)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

[image: Problem]

It's a problem from a past-paper. So what is this notation tell me to do? How should I start solving this?

Please tell me where should I start? I'm confused with the notation that $J$ points

Comment: This denotes the [jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) or its determinant, named after Carl Gustav Jacob Jacobi.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun thank you very much

Comment: @Gribouillis thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It denotes the *Jacobian matrix* of a function from $\mathbf R^3$ to  $\mathbf R^3$:
$$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial (u,v,w)}\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}&
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial w} \\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}&
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial w} \\
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}&
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w} 
\end{bmatrix}.$$